# Java - How to wait until uploadFileToBlockBlob has finished?

Tags: java, azure

Having a problem with Azure's sdk v10, when I'm uploading files the code carries on while the upload does its thing, but I'd really like to hold until the upload finishes.

I saw c# has an 'await' function, is there a Java way to handle this?

```
try{

    AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(file.toPath());

    TransferManager.uploadFileToBlockBlob(fileChannel, blob, 8*1024*1024, null, null)
        .subscribe( azureResponse -> {
        logger.info("Status code: " + azureResponse.response().statusCode());
        if( azureResponse.response().statusCode() != 201){
            logger.error("upload failed - " + azureResponse.response().body());
            // throw exception
        }
    });
} catch( Exception e ) {
  // handle the exception
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with azure in particular but perhaps you can write a while loop that blocks thread executing until the upload process has finished. Something as simple as this should do the trick provided you have a separate boolean method that returns `true` when the file has finished uploading:

```
while(!hasFileUploaded()) 
{
    // do nothing here
}
```

I am sorry if this answer seems a bit generic but without further knowledge about how and where the file is being uploaded I can't tell you exactly how to validate the upload process.